# Limtations of dynamic objects in C#/Java

Tags: c#, java, c++

I'm basically a C++ guy trying to venture into C#. From the basic tutorial of C#,  I happen to find that all objects are created and stored dynamically (also true for Java) and are accessed by references and hence there's no need for copy constructors. There is also no need of  bitwise copy when passing objects to a function or returning objects from a function. This makes C# much simpler than C++.

However, I read somewhere that operating on objects exclusively through references imposes limitations on the type of operations that one can perform thus restricting the programmer of complete control. One limitation is that the programmer cannot precisely specify when an object can be destroyed.

Can someone please elaborate on other limitations? (with a sample code if required)

Comment: Not a limitation, but a mitigation of the limitation you mention: in C#, `using` blocks can get you most of what you want out of being able to specify when an object is destroyed in C++. They're not exactly the same thing, but they make lack of explicit destruction much less painful.

Comment: Aren't C# & Java both garbage collected languages? Isn't the destructor called in both when the garbage collector reaps the object?

Comment: The IDisposable interface also has these cases in mind. BUT that should only be used when necessary. You see, having a GC actually clears your mind of those things.

Comment: Yes. But this is not in the hands of programmer. In C++, the objects are destroyed when they go out of scope. This gives some sort of control to the programmer.

Comment: In my own humble experience: the biggest bump in the road when transitioning from C++ to C# or Java: accepting that it is not about losing complete control but instead about a runtime supporting you.

Comment: What is a dynamic object? I don't think you're using the right terminology here. Do you mean a heap allocated object vs stack allocated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the "limitations" are by design rather than considered a deficiency (you may not agree of course)

You cannot determine/you don't have to worry about

- when an object is destroyed
- where the object is in memory
- how big it is (unless you are tuning the application)
- using pointer arithmetic
- accessing out side an object
- accessing an object with the wrong type
- sharing objects between threads is simpler
- whether the object is on the stack or the heap. (The stack is being used more and more in Java)
- fragmentation of memory (This is not true of all collectors)

Answer (score 1):

Because of Garbage collection done in java we cannot predict when the object will get destroyed but it performs the work of destructor.

If you want to free up some resources then you can use finally block.

```
try {


  } finally{
  // dispose resources.     
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it is quite performs the work of destructor` ? This is not grammatical English.

Comment: I meant to say that it performs the work of destructor as is done in c++.

Answer (score 0):

Having made a similar transition, the more you look into it, the more you *do* have to think about C#'s GC behaviour in all but the most straighforward cases. This is especially true when trying to handle unmanaged resources from managed code.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About) highlights a lot of the issues you may be interested in.

Personally I miss a reference counted alternative to *IDisposable* (more like shared_ptr), but that's probably a hangover from a C++ background.

The more I have to write my own plumbing to support C++ like programming, the more likely it is there is another C# mechanism I've overlooked, or I end up getting frustrated with C#. For example, *swap* and *move* are not common idioms in C# as far as I've seen and I miss them: other programmers with a C# background may well disagree about how useful those idioms are.